# How to interpret grails datasource

Tags: grails, datasource

I am reading Grails in Action and it says to use

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:devDB;shutdown=true" 
}
```

This causes an error when I run grails console: Unsupported connection setting "SHUTDOWN"

grails console works fine when I remove ;shutdown=true

What is shutdown=true meant to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described here: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html

It's probably not useful for an in-memory database since it is lost when the web server stops anyway.

Comment: Is it really lost in this case? It says 'file' - so I assume that it is persisted to a file when the server is shut down. Surely not too reliable...

Comment: What database does jdbc:h2:file:devDB use?  Is it related to hsqldb?

Comment: `jdbc:h2:file:devDB` is the H2 syntax for creating a database; in 2.0 we switched from HSQLDB to [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) for the default database